# Rails: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting ')' '.freeze; end ^~~

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm creating a very basic rails app (learning tutorial) and can't understand why I'm getting this error.

I've tried troubleshooting but to no avail.

```
<div id="page_wrapper">
    <h1> Make Something </h1>

    <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
        <% if @post.errors.any? %>
            <div id="errors">
                <h2> <%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error" %> stopped this post from saving </h2>
                <ul>
                    <% @post.errors.full_message.each do |msg| %>
                        <li> <%= msg %> </li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
            </div>

        <% end %>
        <p>
            <%= f.label :title %> <br>
            <%= f.text_field :title %>
        </p>

        <p>
            <%= f.label :body %> <br>
            <%= f.text_area :body %>
        </p>

        <p>
            <%= f.submit %>
        </p>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

I expect the better UI error messages, but no idea what my error is - I'm sure it's a very minor syntax fix, but your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing the brackets when calling pluralize

change

```
<h2> <%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error" %> stopped this post from saving </h2>
```

to

```
<h2> <%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> stopped this post from saving </h2>
```